# Overlaying parts of an SVG with a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying make certain parts of an SVG rendered by [OpenSheetMusicDisplay](https://opensheetmusicdisplay.github.io/) clickable. My strategy is to overlay them with transparent divs. Every graphical OSMD object has a [BoundingBox](https://opensheetmusicdisplay.github.io/classdoc/classes/boundingbox.html) with relative and absolut positions in SVG coordinates. How do I translate these coordinates to something I can put into `div.style.left`, etc?

Comment: Why do you need to use transparent divs?  Why not just make the SVG elements clickable?

Comment: Because the areas i want input events on consist of several components and not all logical elements have corresponding graphical elements.